# Could not load type 'spr᩟' from assembly Spire.XLS

Tags: c#, .net, spire.xls

I`m using the latest FreeSpire.Xls library with .net 7

When i touch this

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook()
```

i have an error

```
Could not load type 'spr᩟' from assembly 'Spire.XLS, Version=12.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=663f351905198cb3' because it attempts to implement a class as an interface.
```

Perhaps there is little information here if you need something - just write

Comment: Just tried with Nuget (FreeSpire.Office 8.2.0).  Works for me.  Which version do you have?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock I`m using the latest version of FreeSpire.Xls (12.7.0)

Comment: Try using the office package as I did.  That includes xls and worked for me (latest 8.2.0)